# Как ответить на вопрос о времени правильно?

Tags: лексика, общие-вопросы

Например:

- 6 часов 45 минут,
- 45 минут седьмого,
- седьмой час,
- без четверти семь.

Comment: Yaroslav Holod: _необходимы еще возможные варианты_ === Шесть сорок пять. === Сорок пять седьмого.

Comment: Без пятнадцати семь.

Comment: Предлагают заменить на «который час», и вдогонку — вариант: «сколько на ваших».

Comment: "Некоторый час" говорили *вскоре после начала* этого часа, а не к концу его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Семь скоро.

Да почти семь.

Все справки платны.

Простите, часов не ношу.

А сколько вам хотелось бы?

Чёрт, скоро семь, футбол начинается...

Шесть сорок шесть будет, как только договорю.

Comment: Наш без четверти.

Comment: Насчёт футбола Вы что-то перепутали. ;)

Comment: Если перепутал, то не в словах; они оказались пророческими - проворонил сегодня весь футбол, понадеявшись, что он после девяти.

Comment: Сочувствую... Зато мы вышли в финальную стадию, так что всё впереди.)) Я имел в виду, что тут семь, а не 19 часов, а футбола по утрам не бывает.)

Comment: Если у человека часы со стрелкой, они только 7 показывают, он читает что видит.

Answer (score 1):

Без выпендрёжа если: без четверти семь.

А как неохваченный вариант - старинное: шесть и три четверти; шесть с тремя четвертями.

---

[**Как правильно: сколько времени или который час?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_68)

> Традиционная форма вопроса-обращения о времени который час? На этот
>   вопрос вы можете дать ответ: пятый час, шестой, пошел уже восьмой час.
>   Но и ответ с указанием часов и минут тоже будет правильным. Вопрос
>   сколько времени? по сравнению с вопросом который час? новый. В
>   «Толковом словаре русского языка: В 4 т.» под редакцией Дмитрия
>   Николаевича Ушакова (М., 1935-1939) вопрос этот снабжен пометой
>   «разговорное», но сегодня вопросы сколько времени? и который час? –
>   равноправные варианты. Если же вам необходимо спросить о времени
>   начала или окончания работы магазина, учреждения, то вы задаете вопрос
>   «В котором часу Вы открываете / закрываете магазин?» или «Во сколько
>   открывается / закрывается магазин?» И еще очень часто можно услышать
>   распространенную ошибку Доскольки работает магазин? (Не знаем, как и
>   написать это неправильное доскольки – такое слово в словарях русского
>   языка не зафиксировано.) Правильно: до скольких работает магазин? Или,
>   в другой ситуации, до скольких ты будешь на работе? до скольких тебя
>   ждать?. Запомнить эту форму слова сколько легко: у слова сколько
>   ударение неподвижное, оно во всех формах падает на первых слог:
>   сколько, скольких коллег я встретил, скольким людям я обязан,
>   сколькими друзьями я обзавелся; о скольких встречах я мечтаю.
>
> Лидия Корнеевна Чуковская в «Записках об Анне Ахматовой» передает
>   слова  Анны Андреевны: «Вы знаете, я считаю неприличным делать
>   замечания людям, если они неверно говорят. Неприличным и пошлым.
>   Ничего не поправляю. Всё переношу. Но вот "во сколько" вместо "в
>   котором часу" или вместо "когда", - тут она задохнулась от гнева и
>   дальше произнесла по складам, - я вы-нес-ти не мо-гу. И "мы живем в
>   Кратово" вместо "в Кратове" - тоже не могу».

**Правильно:**
**сколько времени и который час.**